# NameError: undefined local variable or method `desired_preferences'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have created a module with a method

```
module Adding_preferences
  def desired_preferences            
    @preference = %w(motabilitySpecialist newCars bodyshop filter8 filter7).each do |selection|            
      @browser.label(:for,  selection ).click    
    end
  end
end
```

I have included this module into a class:

```
class Pages
  include Adding_preferences

  attr_accessor :browser, :preference

  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
  end
end

World do
  Pages.new
end
```

I am calling this method in a Cucumber scenario

```
When /^I select a desired preference$/ do
  desired_preferences
end
```

But at runtime I receive an error, "NameError: undefined local variable or method `desired_preferences'". Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Have you restart your server after adding the `desired_preferences` method in module??

Comment: Where is `desired_preferences` called? Can you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: restart server?? This is a Watir/cucumber application no explicit server

Answer (score 1):

When you include a module to a class you can use this method in the instance methods of this class. You cant call the included method in a View that displays the data from the model that includes the module. For me it looks like you just dont use the `desired_preferences` method in an instance method.

Please show us the peace of code you try to call the method if this still doesnt help you out.

// The naming of the Module is not conventional. You should call it `module AddingPreferences`  isntead of`module Adding_preferences` and the file should be named `adding_preferences.rb` then try to `include AddingPreferences`

Comment: I have included where the method is being called

Comment: Is it a class or an instance method?

Comment: could you then please post the whole method?^^

Comment: please also post the name of the file including the module.

Comment: I have the module above and the class which i have included the module into.. I am trying to call  desired_preferences in the cucumber step.. I think its to do with desired_preferences not being initialized??

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea for you to spend some time getting more familiar with Ruby's Class/Module/Object/Method inheritance model, because the way you're structuring your code there is a little bit messy.

However, a simple thing to try (and I'm not going to guarantee that it will work flawlessly) is the following modifications:

Assign your instantiated Pages class to a class instance variable:

```
World do
  @page = Pages.new
end
```

...and then use that instance variable in your step definition...

```
When /^I select a desired preference$/ do
  @page.desired_preferences
end
```

I hope that helps!